# Add 'Last modified by ...' footer to each page

Tags: 7, nodes

How do I add a footer to each page generated by Drupal (7) so to show the identity of the last user that modified that page? (together with the modification date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with something like this, note that this is only pseduo code and is not tested:

```
 // get the user that made the latest modification
 // for a node of type 'page'
 function getLatestPageUpdater() {
     $query = "SELECT n.changed, u.* FROM node n 
               INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = n.uid
               WHERE n.type = 'page' 
               ORDER BY changed DESC 
               LIMIT 1";
     return db_query($query)->fetch();
 }
```

Then in your `page.tpl.php` you could do like this:

```
 <?php $user = getLatestPageUpdater();
       if($user):
 ?>
 <p>Last edited <?php print $user->changed; ?> by <?php print $user->name; ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Like [@tostinni](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/594/tostinni) pointed out Drupal doesn't track the last editor of a node, so the above code would always display the original author of the node. If you're using [node revisions](https://drupal.org/node/320614) I think you should be able to do something like this (again this is only pseudo code and is not tested):

```
function getLatestPageUpdater($node) {
  $query = "SELECT u.name
            FROM node_revisions nr, users u
            WHERE nr.uid = u.uid
            AND nr.nid = ".$node->nid."
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC
            LIMIT 1";
  return db_query($query)->fetch();
}

<?php if($node->type == "page"): ?>
<?php $user = getLatestPageUpdater($node); 
      if($user): 
?>
<p>Last edited <?php print $node->changed; ?> by <?php print $user->name; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Umberto - Nice it solved your problem.

Comment: @Umberto I know this is quite late. `page.tpl.php` already defines a `$node` variable that contains information about the currently loaded node, including exactly the information you're looking for. There is no need to perform an extra DB query in your template to fetch it.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I'm late on this one but don't forget that Drupal doesn't track the last username that changed the node, so `<?php print $user->name; ?>` will always display the author of the node.

Comment: @tostinni - You're completely right. Didn't knew that Drupal wasn't tracking the user who changed a post. I guess the above code could be modified to grab the last editor if one were to use revisions.

Comment: it's "node_revision" not "node_revisions"

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [*Last Modification* Date module for drupal](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/droetker/2467991) that does exactly that.

ATM this is still a sandbox project, but it is in approval state.

It just creates a block that spits out the last modification date of any node in the system. There is no database polling, saving of that date is done *at node save time*. So no overhead.